# I get this error importing firebase_auth: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

this is the package I can't import: firebase_auth: ^3.2.0

I tried importing different verions of it also flutter clean. I also tried `flutter pub get`, `flutter pub upgrade`, `flutter pub outdated` and none worked. I restarted the IDE several times and even created a new project but I stil get the same error in both VS Code and Android Studio.

Here is my pubspect.yaml

```
    version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/
```

Answer (score 0):

I used both older versions of firebase_core & firebase_auth and my issue resolved.

```
firebase_core: ^1.0.0
firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).